# Creating a password recovery table - Error when inserting a value

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, doctrine

I have a User class with attributes like id, name, mail, etc.
I'm implementing the password recovery process, so I created a `password_recovery` table with these columns:

- id
- user_id
- token
- createdDate
- expiryDate
- isExpired

This is my `PasswordRecovery` Class:

```
namespace \UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="password_recovery")
 */
class PasswordRecovery {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**  
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $idUser;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string") 
     */
    private $token;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime() 
    */
    private $createdDate;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime") 
     * @Assert\DateTime() 
    */
    private $expireDate;

     /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean") 
    */
    private $expired; }
```

When the user wants to recover his password, he must enter his email. If the mail is in the db, I create a `PasswordRecovery` Object and store it in the db. This is how I'm doing that: (small part of the code)

```
if (!empty($resetMail))
        {

        $recovery = new PasswordRecovery();

        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
        $recovery->setToken($token);
        $userId = $resetMail->getId();
        $recovery->setIdUser($userId);


        $recovery->setCreatedDate(new \DateTime('now'));

        $expiry = (new \DateTime('now + 1day')); 
        $recovery->setExpireDate($expiry);
        $recovery->setExpired(false);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($recovery);
        $em->flush(); }
```

I got this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to \UserBundle\Entity\PasswordRecovery::setIdUser() must be an instance of \UserBundle\Entity\User, integer given, called in /home/user/project/src/UserBundle/Controller/AccountController.php on line 553 and defined
```

Why?

Comment: From the error message, it looks like IdUser needs to be a "User" object, not the ID of the user.

Comment: yes, but `idUser` references the User `id`, which is a INT

Comment: One of the biggest conceptual hurdles to understanding Doctrine ORM is to transition from sql database thinking (ids) to object thinking.  PasswordRecovery objects are linked to User objects.  That fact that you defined the user property as an integer means nothing.  You can avoid loading in the complete user object by creating a reference to the object using getReference instead of find.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setIdDUser(User)`. This is a proxy object because it's a reference to another table (entity)

In the same way when you call `getIdUser()` you will get a proxy object again, which you will have to call `getId()` on if you want the int value.